# Average-version of cumsum in data.table (cumulative mean)

Tags: r, data.table

I have some data

```
library(data.table); set.seed(42)
dat <- data.table(t=1:6, group=rep(1:2,each=3), val=runif(6,0,1))
> dat
   t group       val
1: 1     1 0.9148060
2: 2     1 0.9370754
3: 3     1 0.2861395
4: 4     2 0.8304476
5: 5     2 0.6417455
6: 6     2 0.5190959
```

and I would like to calculate a rolling average of `val` within each `group`. I can get a rolling sum using

```
dat[, cumsum:=cumsum(val), by=group]
> dat
   t group       val    cumsum
1: 1     1 0.9148060 0.9148060
2: 2     1 0.9370754 1.8518815
3: 3     1 0.2861395 2.1380210
4: 4     2 0.8304476 0.8304476
5: 5     2 0.6417455 1.4721931
6: 6     2 0.5190959 1.9912891
```

and I basically would need to divide `cumsum` by the number of rows but I don't know how to do this. I suppose `.N` would keep dividing each value by 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cummean`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
dat[, new :=cummean(val), by=group]
```

Or if we need to divide use `seq_len(.N)`

```
dat[, new1 := cumsum(val)/seq_len(.N), by = group]
```

Comment: `cummean` would be great but it tells me that function was not found.

Comment: `seq_len(.N)` works! Is there a native data.table function, perhaps?

Comment: @bumblebee `.N` is native data.table

Comment: I mean a native version of `cummean`.

Comment: @bumblebee By checking the functions available in data.table, i couldn't find any equivalent in data.table

Comment: Thanks. I always wondered where do I find an overview of these functions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208816/discussion-between-bumblebee-and-akrun).

Comment: CRAN keeps a [Reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf) of all packages